# Variance of standardized linear regression coefficient

Tags: statistics, variance, linear-regression

Suppose we have standardized inputs (mean $0$, variance $1$). So that $y=x_1\beta_1+x_2\beta_2+\varepsilon$, (we have no $\beta_0$ due to standardization). With $\varepsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^{2})$. Also note that we only have 2 variables.

We wish to show that $Var(\beta_1)=\frac{\sigma^{2}}{1-r_{12}^{2}}$, where $r_{12}$ is the sample correlation between $x_1,x_2$.

So I have arrived at $Var(\hat{\beta})=Var((X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y)=Var((X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}(X\beta+\varepsilon))=Var((X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}\sigma^2I) = \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}$

And I'm not exactly sure where to continue, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $X$ is $n\times2$, so $X^\top X$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, which we can invert by hand.

Comment: Hi: This is just a hint but you need to show that the element in first row and first column of the $2 \times 2$ correlation matrix $X^{T} X^{-1} = \frac{1}{1-\rho_{12}}$. Note that this is the standard deviation of $\beta_1$.

Comment: I have tried expanding term, however it is still not obvious to me how it transforms into the desired result

Comment: What do you get for $(X^TX)^{-1}$?

Comment: If $X=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1&b_1\\
a_2&b_2
\end{pmatrix}$ then I got: $(X^TX)^{-1}=[(a_{1}^{2}+a_{2}^{2})(b_{1}^{2}+b_{2}^{2})-(a_1b_1+a_2b_2)^{2}]^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
b_{1}^{2}+b_{2}^{2}&-a_1b_1-a_2b_2\\
-a_1b_1-a_2b_2&a_{1}^{2}+a_{2}^{2}
\end{pmatrix}=[(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)^{2}]^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
b_{1}^{2}+b_{2}^{2}&-a_1b_1-a_2b_2\\
-a_1b_1-a_2b_2&a_{1}^{2}+a_{2}^{2}
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: $X$ is not a $2\times 2$ matrix, but $X^\top X$ is. What is $X$ explicitly (in terms of $x_{1i}$, $x_{2i}$)?

Answer (score 2):

It is a result in regression analysis.

We denote the design matrix $X = (x_1, x_2)$, where $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ supposing we have $n$ sample units (here may be some abuse of notaions since there are $x_1$ and $x_2$ in your problem).

The covariance matrix of estimator of $\beta$ which is already derived in your post is
$$
Var(\hat\beta) = (X^TX)^{-1}\sigma^2
$$

We apply the rule of multipication of block matrix,
$$
\begin{align}
(X^T X)^{-1} &= \left( \begin{pmatrix} x_1^T \\ x_2^T \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1  x_2 \end{pmatrix} \right)^{-1} \\
&= \left( \begin{pmatrix}x_1^Tx_1 & x_1^Tx_2 \\ x_2^T x_1 & x_2^T x_2 \end{pmatrix} \right)^{-1} \\
&=  \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{x_1^Tx_1(1 - \frac{(x_1^Tx_2)^2}{x_1^Tx_1 x_2^T x_2})} & * \\ * & * \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
where the last equation is derived by [the inverse of block matrix equation(2.3)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122101002784).

The $x_1$ and $x_2$ has been standardized then $x_1^T x_1 = -n-1, x_2^Tx_2 = n-1$ and the correlation $r_{12} = cor(x_1, x_2) = \frac{x_1^T x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^Tx_1 x_2^Tx_2}}$.

Hence, $Var(\hat\beta_1) = \frac{\sigma^2}{(n-1)(1 - r_{12}^2)}$.

Btw, you got stuck just because of some trick of algebra. [The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) may be a good reference.

Comment: Why is it that $x_1^{T}x_1=1$  and not n-1?

Comment: @Lehmann, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very comfortable with Mathjax. I provided the solution in the below image, but I believe that there is some missing term in the variance that you mentioned in your question.
If we assume there are n terms available for each dependent and independent variable then

[image: Solution to the above problem with some correction]